# VBA formatting Textboxes in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am struggling to find out how to vertically align textboxes via VBA.

Furthermore, when researching the Autofit feature of Powerpoint, I found quite some posts, that said this can only be changed in the registry, but on my PC, some templates autofit and some don't., Is there some way to turn it off when creating the placeholders in VBA?

Thanks for the help

seba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoFit can be turned on/off for shapes that have text frames (ie, that can contain text):

Assuming a reference to the shape in oSh,

```
oSh.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone ' or ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText
' 0 or 1 respectively
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, on the Autofit the solution is: ActivePresentation.TitleMaster.Shapes.Title.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle

Comment: That doesn't change Autofit.  It changes the anchor point of the textbox.  Autofit controls whether the text box expands to fit the text in it.  The anchor points control which way the text grows/shrinks as you add/subtract text.  Vertical Top means the top of the box stays fixed and it grows downward.  Middle keeps the midpoint of the box fixed and as text is added, the box grows equally up and down.

Comment: I agree, that's of course the solution to my first issue, the vertical alignment.

Comment: Bingo.  yep, that's the ticket.